# git commit creates assets and temporary files for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Whenever I run `git commit -m "blah"`, my apps are creating a bunch of random files, for some reason. This is causing a problem because it is taking up lots of space on my server and my `git push heroku master` command will timeout.

What is happening? Below is the output from my last commit on an almost blank app. The only things I have on the app are these gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'


group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'

end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

And a simple bootstrap carousel on the home page. However all these other files get created on the git commit:

```
$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) 8684d20] first commit
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.lock.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.rdoc.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Rakefile.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/controllers/application_controller.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/controllers/pages_controller.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/helpers/application_helper.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/helpers/pages_helper.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in bin/bundle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in bin/rails.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in bin/rake.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config.ru.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/application.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/boot.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/database.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/environment.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/environments/development.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/environments/production.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/environments/test.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/inflections.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/mime_types.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/session_store.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/locales/en.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/routes.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in config/secrets.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in db/seeds.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/404.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/422.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/500.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/robots.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test/helpers/pages_helper_test.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test/test_helper.rb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 64 files changed, 971 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 Gemfile
 create mode 100644 Gemfile.lock
 create mode 100644 README.rdoc
 create mode 100644 Rakefile
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/pic1.JPG
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/pic2.JPG
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/pic3.JPG
 create mode 100644 app/assets/javascripts/application.js
 create mode 100644 app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee
 create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
 create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/pages.css.scss
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/application_controller.rb
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/concerns/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
 create mode 100644 app/helpers/application_helper.rb
 create mode 100644 app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
 create mode 100644 app/mailers/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/models/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/models/concerns/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
 create mode 100644 app/views/pages/landing.html.erb
 create mode 100644 bin/bundle
 create mode 100644 bin/rails
 create mode 100644 bin/rake
 create mode 100644 config.ru
 create mode 100644 config/application.rb
 create mode 100644 config/boot.rb
 create mode 100644 config/database.yml
 create mode 100644 config/environment.rb
 create mode 100644 config/environments/development.rb
 create mode 100644 config/environments/production.rb
 create mode 100644 config/environments/test.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/inflections.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/mime_types.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/session_store.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
 create mode 100644 config/locales/en.yml
 create mode 100644 config/routes.rb
 create mode 100644 config/secrets.yml
 create mode 100644 db/seeds.rb
 create mode 100644 lib/assets/.keep
 create mode 100644 lib/tasks/.keep
 create mode 100644 log/.keep
 create mode 100644 public/404.html
 create mode 100644 public/422.html
 create mode 100644 public/500.html
 create mode 100644 public/favicon.ico
 create mode 100644 public/robots.txt
 create mode 100644 test/controllers/.keep
 create mode 100644 test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb
 create mode 100644 test/fixtures/.keep
 create mode 100644 test/helpers/.keep
 create mode 100644 test/helpers/pages_helper_test.rb
 create mode 100644 test/integration/.keep
 create mode 100644 test/mailers/.keep
 create mode 100644 test/models/.keep
 create mode 100644 test/test_helper.rb
 create mode 100644 vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
 create mode 100644 vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
```

Anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're committing newly created rails application files.
Everything seems fine. Bunch of rails app files and .keep files to keep folders in repo.

> 64 files changed, 971 insertions(+)

no big deal

Answer (score 1):

Not an issue but if you want, you can turn off the messages by puttting this in your git core config

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: I don't care much about the messages but about the insertions that you see if you scroll down underneath the message