# Ruby on Rails, Git and CRLF - nontrivial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, newline, core.autocrlf

I am learning Ruby on Rails and I use Windows 7. When I try to commit my changes to Git, I receive the `fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF` message.

It seems that `rails generate` generates files with LF, not CRLF. Of course, I may switch from

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf true
```

to

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf warn
```

but I don't like the possibility of crushing any committed binary into pieces.

I tried to avoid the problem with `.gitattributes`, but my lines like

```
* text=auto
*.rb text
```

do not help.

Is there a way to make Rails generate files with CRLF ending? Or is there a way to make Git auto-transform the `.rb` and `.erb` files, but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't like the possibility of crushing any committed binary into
>   pieces.

Are you sure that's a real problem?

If you turn the warnings off (`core.autocrlf true`) git will make the adjustments when you commit and you can continue being productive.

If you truly have a solid reason for not wanting to do this you are going to have difficulty as I don't think there is a simple way (there is always *some* way) to have Rails generate files with the CRLF ending and it's weird to have git auto-transform based on file type.

I can certainly be wrong, but it seems like you're trying a bit too much to work against your tools?

Possibly useful reference: [git commit creates assets and temporary files for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317735/git-commit-creates-assets-and-temporary-files-for-some-reason)

If you *really* want to go down the road of attempting to configure git to make these changes you can check out a git attribute filter driver as suggested in this response: [Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)

Another useful reference to the above proposed solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/1026898